# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop [another variant]

Tags: reactjs

I read some articles on this topic, but it didn't helped. I think my problem is a little different

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../store';
import ToDoAdder from '../ToDoAdder/ToDoAdder';

function ToDoList() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [todosState, setTodosState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/`);
    const res = await data.json();
    console.log(res, 0);
    setUsers(res);
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/');
    const res = await data.json();

    const needed = res.slice(0, 10);
    setTodosState(needed);

    return res;
  };

  console.log(todosState);
  const todosWithUser = todosState.map((o) => {
    const user = users.filter((i) => o.userId === i.id)[0];
    o.user = user;
    return o;
  });

  store.dispatch({ type: 'add/todoArray', payload: { todos: todosWithUser } });

  const todos = useSelector((store) => store.toDos);
  // console.log(todos);
  return (
    /* some statement */
  );
}

export default ToDoList;
```

Tell me how can I solve this ? I know that my problem is in **setTodosState**, but I cant solve that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

never call any change state inside component. It need to call it on the function or hooks effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const todosWithUser = todosState.map((o) => {
    const user = users.filter((i) => o.userId === i.id)[0];
    o.user = user;
    return o;
  });

  store.dispatch({ type: "add/todoArray", payload: { todos: todosWithUser } });
}, [todosState]);
```

Comment: I had a similar problem when I check the user is logged in or not by getting values from local storage. When I call the function without useEffect it is rendered multiple times & gives the same error, by calling it in useEffect it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem with your code:

```
store.dispatch({ type: 'add/todoArray', payload: { todos: todosWithUser } });
```

Every time `ToDoList` is rendered, this dispatch will be invoke causing the redux state to change, and you also have this selector in your code:

```
const todos = useSelector((store) => store.toDos);
```

So it will again render `ToDoList` making the render loop infinite

---

So let's put your dispatch into eventHandler or a useEffect hook.